# Reading a text file by recursively skipping rows using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data file looks like this,

```
# some text
# some text
# some text
100000 3 4032
 1 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 2 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 3 0.0625 84.13 291.859
200000 3 4032
 4 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 5 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 6 0.0625 84.13 291.859
300000 3 4032
 7 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 8 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 9 0.0625 84.13 291.859
........
```

I want to read these data in to an array for further processing. However I only need data with four columns. Therefore, either I have to skip three column data or store them in a different array. Since this data file is large and repeating the same way, it would be easier if I could read this in one shot. 
I have tried numpy.genfromtxt(file) with itertools.islice(file,4,7) however couldn't find a way to store all the four column data to a single array(because of the three column data in between). 
Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
import itertools as IT   
import numpy as np

arr=[]

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:    
     ln = IT.islice(f, 4, 7)   
     arr.append(np.genfromtxt(ln))     
     ln = IT.islice(f, 1, 4)   
     arr.append(np.genfromtxt(ln))
     ln = IT.islice(f, 1, 4)   
     arr.append(np.genfromtxt(ln))
print arr
```

This code works however my data file is much larger than above example. Therefore, I don't want to repeat the code as it will not be efficient. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Show us your code and describe how it is not meeting your expectations.

Comment: Please insert a relevant part of your data as *text* in your question, rather than linking to some external image.

Comment: Can you write a file reader that reads all lines, but just passes on lines with 4 columns?  Sort of like reading a file but skipping comment lines.  `genfromtxt` is happy with anything that gives it lines - a file, a generator, a list of lines.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you want.

```
from io import StringIO
dataFile = StringIO('''\
# some text
# some text
# some text
100000 3 4032
 1 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 2 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 3 0.0625 84.13 291.859
200000 3 4032
 4 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 5 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 6 0.0625 84.13 291.859
300000 3 4032
 7 0.0125 101.27 293.832
 8 0.0375 108.624 292.285
 9 0.0625 84.13 291.859''')

def wantedLines():
    count = -1
    with dataFile as data:
        while True:
            line = data.readline()
            if line: line = line.strip()
            else: break
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            else:
                count +=1
                if count % 4==0: continue
                else: yield line.encode()

import numpy as np

result = np.genfromtxt(wantedLines())
print (result)
```

`result`:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   1.25000000e-02   1.01270000e+02   2.93832000e+02]
 [  2.00000000e+00   3.75000000e-02   1.08624000e+02   2.92285000e+02]
 [  3.00000000e+00   6.25000000e-02   8.41300000e+01   2.91859000e+02]
 [  4.00000000e+00   1.25000000e-02   1.01270000e+02   2.93832000e+02]
 [  5.00000000e+00   3.75000000e-02   1.08624000e+02   2.92285000e+02]
 [  6.00000000e+00   6.25000000e-02   8.41300000e+01   2.91859000e+02]
 [  7.00000000e+00   1.25000000e-02   1.01270000e+02   2.93832000e+02]
 [  8.00000000e+00   3.75000000e-02   1.08624000e+02   2.92285000e+02]
 [  9.00000000e+00   6.25000000e-02   8.41300000e+01   2.91859000e+02]]
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. I appreciate your help.